# How should I frame the data and send multiple bytes over uart?

Tags: embedded, esp32, uart, esp-idf

I m trying to write the code for on switch board touch sensor which communication with mcu(esp32) using the uart protocol. There we have frame of packet which we have to write to uart to get the reading. Let me share some documentation,

```
1.

In API frame structure following is the fixed definition of any command frame

     Every first byte of frame is fixed 0x7B (“{” in ASCII, 123 in decimal).
    Every second byte of frame is ‘command type’ byte, it informs what you need to do with rest of the data. This will act as a frame Identifier in the data received from touch panel (response frame and event frame)
    Third byte is length of frame. It is 1-byte value (L - 4) where L is total numbers of bytes of whole frame.
    Second Last byte is checksum. Checksum is a lower byte of addition of whole individual bytes of frame except First byte (Start byte), Second byte (Command type byte), 
       Second Last byte (Checksum byte itself) and Last byte is 0x7D.
    Last byte is 0x7D, it is End code to indicate the end of frame. (“}” in ASCII, 125  in decimal).

For Example, consider following frame.
Table 1.1 Frame example 1.

1st Byte    2nd Byte    3rd Byte    4th Byte    5th Byte    6th Byte
0x7B        0x03        0x02        0x05        0x07        0x7D
Start Code  Command     Length         Data        Checksum     End Code

So the checksum will be lower byte of addition of third byte and fourth byte.
0x02 + 0x05 = 0x07 so we will consider 0x07 as checksum here.


Example 2, consider following frame.
Table 1.2 Frame example 2.

1st Byte    2nd Byte    3rd Byte    4th Byte    5th Byte    6th Byte    7th Byte    8th Byte
0x7B        0x52        0x04        0x02        0xFF        0x14        0x19        0x7D
Start Code  Frame       Length      Data        Data        Data        Checksum    End Code          
            Identifier

In this example 2 the checksum will be lower byte of addition of third to sixth byte.
0x04 + 0x02 + 0xFF + 0x14 = 0x0119 so we will consider 0x19 as checksum here.

2. 

    Blink LED (All slider LED) control.
    1.Command
    
    This package is used to control blinking of LED. Hardware Version 2.0 has dedicated status LED. Which will be used to indicate status of product as on need. 
    
    Table 1.6 Blink LED command package detail.
    Status  1st Byte    2nd Byte    3rd Byte    4th Byte        5th Byte            6th Byte    8th Byte
    Start   0x7B        0x05        0x03    0x01  (Start)   (0x01 to 0xNN*)     Checksum    0x7D
    Stop    0x7B        0x05        0x03    0x00  (Stop)     0x00               Checksum    0x7D
        Start Code      Command     Length              Pulse with (x100ms)     Checksum    End Code
    
    To start status LED blinking, the start command frame is sent with required value of 4th byte as 0x01. For Example, to make status LED blinking as time duration 200ms, the value of 5th byte is 0x02. 
    And to stop status LED blinking the stop frame is sent
    
    2.Response
    Table 1.7 Blink LED response detail.
    
    1st Byte    2nd Byte    3rd Byte    4th Byte    5th Byte
    0x7B        0x55        0x01        0x01        0x7D
```

n 1 point, we can able to see how uart frame should be. In 2 point, I want to read and write the frame command to stop and start blinkin the led.

**My question is**

- how should I send multiple bytes over uart?
- Does I need to send make a frame of packets? If Yes then How should I do
  that?
- Also, how should I read the response of it?

I did research on how frame the packet and send frame over uart but not found any useful blogs and answer.

**More Info:**

```
Language: C
Compiler: GCC 
MCU: ESP32
```

Hope I m able to explain it.

Thanks in advance for the help!!

Comment: What framework/programming language are you using? Please mention it and update the tags accordingly. Also remove "driver" tag (does not match your question) and replace "esp" with "esp32" tag.

Comment: Commonly you can call a UART function that takes an array of bytes and a length. Prepare that array to call the function. If you've got just a function to send one byte, call it as often as needed with the respective values. -- The receiving part will be quite similar. -- What do you mean by "_make a frame_"? We need some more context, like your programming language, the compiler system, what you have tried so far, and so on.

Comment: @thebusybee here is the link of the uart [function](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/peripherals/uart.html#_CPPv416uart_write_bytes11uart_port_tPKv6size_t) . I want to know if I use array of bytes , does I have to send the byte individaually or sending the address of array will work. `And thanks for the usefull comment`

Comment: You need to call that function just once for the array. Don't forget to pass the actual numbers of bytes to send. What stops you from trying in the first place? An oscilloscope to watch the TX line is most valuable, you should use it to gain some experience.

Comment: I m not good writing the library. So, I thought make sure of everything, before writing the code. Thanks for the clarifying the doubts. @thebusybee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sending multiple bytes**

Sending multiple bytes is straight-forward with the ESP-IDF framework. Let's assume your command frame is in an array called `frame` and the length (in bytes) of the frame is stored in `frame_length`:

```c
uint8_t frame[] = { 0x7B, 0x03, 0x02, 0x05, 0x07, 0x7D };
int frame_length = 6;
uart_write_bytes(uart_port, frame, frame_length);
```

The bigger challenge is probably how to construct the frame in the first place, in particular how to calculate the checksum.

**Sending multiple frames**

Sending multiple frames is straight-forward as well. Just call the above function multiple times. The protocol has been carefully designed such that the receiver is able to split the stream of bytes into frames.

You should prevent however that multiple tasks sends frames concurrently. That way the communication could get mixed up.

**Receiving frames**

Receiving isn't a problem either. Just read frame by frame. It's a two step process:

1. Read 3 bytes. The third byte provides the length of the frame.
2. Read the remaining bytes.

It could look like so:

```c
#define MAX_FRAME_LENGTH 80

uint8_t frame[MAX_FRAME_LENGTH];
int frame_length = 0;

int read_frame(uint8_t* frame) {
    uart_read_bytes(uart_port, frame, 3, portMAX_DELAY);
    uart_read_bytes(uart_port, frame + 3, frame[2] + 4, portMAX_DELAY);
    return frame[2] + 4;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Can you explain me how we get the idea or logic that reading the frame will 2 step process or 3 step process, this step I have to do first and then this step second, like that? Hope I m able explain what I want to know.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your question. Please be more specific in your question and don't just talk about "step" and "process".

Comment: sorry @codo, I want to know when we start writing the library or driver of sensor how we analyze that what step come first. For example, here you said receiving the frame will be two step process. What you sees there and you get the idea of that? Why it should not done in one step instead of two?

Comment: @ also, you said the `The bigger challenge is probably how to construct the frame in the first place` and In above code  easily frame the packet (`uint8_t frame[] = { 0x7B, 0x03, 0x02, 0x05, 0x07, 0x7D })`. Is there any chances this method cause any issue?

Comment: When reading a frame, it is not known up-front how long the frame is. Yet `uart_read_bytes()` requires the length. So the proposed solution is to call `uart_read_bytes()` twice. There might be other solutions.

Comment: @code thanks for the help. I got my answer

Comment: The example for sending a frame always sends the same frame. But if you want to send different frames, possibly containing variable values, the example is too simple. You will then need to calculate the checksum and store it in the frame. I don't know the details of your application or the details of the sensor protocol. Possibly a single fixed frame is sufficient.

Comment: @Codo A mental model that helps me a lot is to think as the application, and the provided functions like `uart_write_bytes()` and `uart_read_bytes()` are messages given to friends. As a programmer I need to prepare a checklist of _steps_ for each different _process_, that works in all cases I want to cover. You are almost there, just practice, and don't be afraid of making errors. Making errors is a good way of getting to know what does not work. What will be left, is one way that works. I'm doing this for 40+ years, and yet today I'm making errors, and I appreciate it.

Comment: UART can lost any bits and bytes. There is already SLIP, why one should reinvent the wheel?

Comment: It looks as if the protocol is given and cannot be changed. But you'd have to ask the OP about that.